# Rectilinear Polygon Decomposition in Python

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I'm trying to find a library that works for decomposing (or partitioning) a rectilinear polygon into separate rectangles. Some libraries such as [poly_decomp](https://github.com/wsilva32/poly_decomp.py) are for Python 2 and while I was able to get it to work for Python 3, it does not work for polygons with holes. [Pode](https://pypi.org/project/pode/), is entirely under documented, and no amount of tinkering has worked in my favor.

Effectively I want to take some arbitrary rectilinear polygon with holes from a shapely polygon, decompose it, and covert it back to multiple shapely polygons.

An example of such a polygon is:

```py
from shapely import Polygon
ext = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)]
interior = [(0.25, 0.25), (0.25, 1.25), (1.25, 1.25), (1.25, 0.25)]
polygon = Polygon(ext, [interior])
```

I've looked into [related research](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717108800223), but I would prefer not to implement my own solution if possible.

Is anyone familiar with a python libraries that work with polygons containing holes and is documented enough to work with?

Comment: The `poly_decomp` repository you've linked has a fork that says they migrated the code from python2 to python3 https://github.com/Easy121/poly_decomp.py I haven't looked too hard at the code, but it seems `2to3` should be able to handle most (if not all) of the required changes, and that appears to be what Easy121 did

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It wasn't too hard to convert to python3, the main issue is that `poly_decomp` doesn't work with polygons containing holes.

Comment: @TheDeafOne: did you had any luck with this ?  I am exactly in need of the same - if you could provide your solution - that would be of great help .

Comment: @kil47 unfortunately nothing yet. I'll post a solution if I find either a simple solution or a library that works well.